# Image doen't take whole the header size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a slider , consists with 3 images , but I'm facing a problem.

I want to put the image to the top of the head .. 
I made the navbar height :0  , to put the navbar above the header ..

you can see the code , and the image will show you what i need exactly

```js
$('.header').height($(window).height());
```

```css
.my-navbar
{
   
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

        

              <div class="my-navbar">
                    <div class="my-container">
                            <div class="user">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <a href="#" class="upper">login</a>
                                <span class="separator">|</span>
                                <a href="#" class="upper">register</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="social">   <!-- social and search icon-->
                                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="links upper txcolor">

                                <a href="#">news</a>
                                <span>|</span>
                                <a href="#">download</a>
                                 <span>|</span>
                                <a href="#">usefull links</a>


                          </div>

                        </div>
            </div>
        
        
        
      <div class="header">
           
        
            

           <!--<div class="slider">
                <div class="my-container">
                    
                    
                      <div class="slider-images">
                          
                    
                     
                       </div>

                    <div class="slider-text">
                    <h3>Four Wheels move the body</h3>
                     <h1>  Two wheels move the soul</h1>
                        
                    </div>
                    

                   

                
                
                </div>
            </div> -->
            
 
            <img src="images/motors/m1.png">
        </div> 
        
        
   
        
        
        <div class="menu">
        
                
                <img  src="images/logo.png" >
            

        
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to set the image size also, it doesn't fill the div by default.

Comment: i mafe it height:100%  . and width : 100%  ,, nut not work

Comment: Do you have any CSS for .header?

Comment: If you set the width and height to 100%, it will take 100% of the parent element, in this case the .header. Try setting it in pixels first to see if it works, or try setting the .header element's hight and width.

Comment: Your slider div class is inside html comment brackets <!-- -->.  First off remove these brackets.  Secondly, no one knows what your actual css is so it's impossible to determine what the height or width of your header is.  However if you're looking for a width and height of !00% on the images, there is a solution that will override the parent css attributes.  Give me a sec and I'll post it below.

Answer (score 0):

```
.slider {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

depending on the display properties of your slider, you might also need to change them to `display:table;`